# PHP - Restrict access to admin page for logged on user

Tags: php, mysql, session

I have a table in my database for users, each user has an auth_level (1-3). On my site I have a admin page for adding/deleting new user accounts, I want to restrict access to this page only to users that have an auth level of 3. 
I have been trying to get this to work with sessions but I am stuck. Hoping someone can help me out.

Here is my code for restricting access. Not sure where I have gone wrong.
the check.php start the session.

```
<?php
require_once('check.php');

//This function returns True if auth level = '3'
//Otherwise it returns False
function CheckAccess()
{
    $result = (isset($_SESSION['SESS_AUTH_LEVEL']) &&  $_SESSION['SESS_AUTH_LEVEL'] == 3 );

    if(!$result)
    {
        header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm=“Test restricted area”');
        header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        header("location: admin.php");
    }
}
?>
```

If I log in as a user with auth level 1 or 3, I get the same blank page.

Comment: Add `ini_set("display_errors", 1);` on top of your page.

Comment: I'm interested to know what would happen if I just loaded "admin.php" directly, as an unauthorised user.

Comment: @Rikesh: He's not. The `}` is for the function `CheckAccess`

Comment: @Rikesh no, when there is no `{` after `else` it will execute the first line code found

Comment: You should decide: Does it return `true` if the user can access, or does it send the user to the new page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you never call `CheckAccess()`. Calling it maybe fixes your error.

Answer (score 1):

It's perfectly valid to do the following, which your function is doing.

```
if (this=that) { /*do multiple*/ } else //do single;
```

However, it appears you are not calling this function? Try this:

```
<?php
  require_once('check.php');
  CheckAccess();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the closing `}` of your function so all the if statement is seen as part of the method by PHP.

Add a `}` after `$result =` and before `if`

A slightly alternative version that should achieve what you want would be

```
<?php

function CheckAccess() {
    $result = (isset($_SESSION['SESS_AUTH_LEVEL']) &&  $_SESSION['SESS_AUTH_LEVEL'] == 3 );
    return $result;
}

if (CheckAccess()) {
    header("location: admin.php");
} else {
    header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm=“Test restricted area”');
    header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
}
```

Comment: Are you sure his CheckAccess function doesn't include the if? Note the closing `}` after the `else header...`

Comment: Nope. when there is no `{` after `else` it will execute the first line code found and there will be no need for the `}`

Comment: Success ! Thanks so much ... working now. I wasnt calling the function! D'oh

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that there is already output before the headers are send:
this need to be changed

```
<?php
require_once('check.php');
?>

<?php

//This function returns True if auth level = '3'


//Otherwise it returns False
function CheckAccess()
{
...
```

to this

```
<?php
require_once('check.php');

//This function returns True if auth level = '3'

//Otherwise it returns False
function CheckAccess()
{
...
```

because the headers needs to be sent first then the content :)

Comment: I'm sorry? What output? unless you are assuming something in `check.php` and what difference does moving `<?php` tags around have? **Ignore that**... whitespace!! I see it now

Comment: @fullybaked haha edited my answer a bit so it's more clear ;)